# How to select and copy the text in the RDLC file?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, reportviewer

I have a **.rdlc** file. I need to select and copy the text in that rdlc file. There is no option to enable the selection and copy the text in the file. I have used below code. Is there any possible way to achieve this behavior. Please share your ideas.

**Code Snippet - Xaml(WPF)**

```
<Grid Margin="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

**Code Snippet - C#**

```
DataTable objdtReport = new DataTable();
SQL.Load();
objdtReport = SQL.GetPatientDischargeDetails(txtBox.Text.Trim());
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WpfApplication7.Users.rdlc";
reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("UserConfiguration", objdtReport.DefaultView));  
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Anyone can please update the solution for this query ?